# Is it possible to do wifi printing or device communication without an ISP?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printing

I've tried to both do networking with just a router and printing. However, it didn't work, even though people have said that it "should" work, and I fallowed all the instructions for networking to a T, then made sure i fallowed the instructions appropriately.

So either I was missing something when I was working on it, or it's necessary to have an internet connection to do wifi communication?

Comment: You don't need the internet to run a network, but you may need it for setting up with the appropriate drivers and other software.

Comment: We'd have to see what instructions, exactly, you were following to a "T", to see where they are wrong. Because either they are wrong (or incomplete), or you are not following them, or you are trying to do something that's not merely networking and printing (such as "cloud print", which is of course dependent on "the cloud" and thus a network connection to the world.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  An ISP gives you internet connectivity, however that is not necessary for a private network.  If your router has DHCP (most do), that will relieve you of a lot of manual configuration.  As others have said, it should work.  If it doesnt, it is most likely a DNS issue.  Use IPs just to make sure everything works, then iron out the kinks as necessary.